Case studies in Carbon Fiber composite tubes to verify FEA
Whenever I build a model of something new, I like to have some analytical results that I can compare with my model so I can reassure myself the model is correct.  I have some resources that show me how to build an FEA model of a carbon fiber laminate tube using Nastran.
I've found plenty of books on micromechanics.  I have one that I'm reading now Mechanics of Composite Structural Elements, Altenbach.  However, it is short on examples.
I'm interested in:

Tubes made from uni-directional fiber layups
Flexural stiffness
Thermal stability (e.g. CTE)

What are some good resources for example carbon fiber tubes and their anisotropic stiffness and CTE?
I'll need the layup, fiber, FVF, ... and the tube properties to compare with my model.

So you want a model to compare to... a model? Composites from unidirectional will be strongly affected by the binder - polyurethane vs epoxy for example will yield very different results.

Yes!  I want an analytical model (formulas) to compare with FEA to verify the FEA is computing what it should compute; to verify I'm using the elements / materials / properties in the FEM correctly.
